# Failed review audit because question was already deleted

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5346659) review audit a few minutes ago and I do not understand why. I clicked the link to the "real" question and it told me that the question has already been removed. So I thought that the the user changed his mind  about posting that question or discovered it was a duplicate or did anything else that could have led to its deletion and clicked "No action needed" on which I failed my audit.

I realise that one review audit is not going to make a difference but still I am curious to as why, even if the system says that the question has already been removed, I still fail my audit if nothing I could have done had any effect on the question because it did not exist any more.

Comment: I already asked this on Meta SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265844/warn-reviewers-about-audits-on-the-privileges-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're supposed to review the question as it appears to you in the review queue:

> ### jQuery Slider with vertical image thumbnails
>
> I need a **responsive** jquery slider with **vertical** thumbnail
>   scroller similar like to this link:
>   http://www.fatemahali.com/#!blank/c3og Can anybody send me link to
>   such jquery carausel .Thanks in advance.

The question is asking for a recommendation for a jQuery plugin, so it should be closed. Clicking **No action needed** was the wrong action to take on such a question.

The fact that you're able to "cheat" review audits by just clicking through to the actual question on the main site is an unfortunate limitation of the audit system, but it's better than nothing, and I suspect that it does manage to catch some reviewers off-guard.

Comment: If a person takes the time to check out the main question in context, very likely they're not a robo-reviewer anyway.  But yes, you do have to make the proper recommendation, the current state of the post notwithstanding.

Comment: Why is this "cheating" feature not disabled for reviewing then? It seems like it would make it much easier for the reviewers to focus on the task at hand.

Comment: @ThreeFx: Because that would be prohibitively difficult / error prone, for marginal benefit as RobertHarvey commented just above you.

Comment: I just had the same problem, an off-topic question came up that was poorly formatted (lacked a code example), first reaction was to edit, then comment requesting an example. Pressed edit and was told the question was deleted, wouldn't let me skip so I assumed it a bug in the review/answered by someone else. Clicked No Action Needed and failed the review.

Comment: There exists an actual cheating feature (as in **not** the "not a robo-reviewer" type). Check to see if the post was apparently posted "2 hours ago". If not, it's a real review. If yes, click the score to see vote counts. If the breakdown is completely different from the previously displayed score (or if an error occurs when fetching vote counts), it's an audit.

Comment: So the problem with this answer is it's wrong. The audit system is too dumb to base its opinion of a question on an old revision.