# Review audit / Already removed / Leaked Information

Tags: discussion, bug

I failed a review audit because I looked at the actual post and saw it was already removed, thus voting “No [further] action needed”. So far, so known: [Failed review audit because question was already deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266228/failed-review-audit-because-question-was-already-deleted)

But I had a reason to check out the post:
[image]

Look at the right column: No other answer and one answer in total. (Check.) This answer is apparently not accepted but the question has an accepted answer. (Uncheck!)

The accepted answer from above states that one should always review what is shown in the review queue. I'm pretty sure they didn't have this situation in mind. So, my questions:

- Should one ignore such details? (Therefore technically being less observant, contrary to what the review system claims to teach.)
- Should this be considered a bug in need of fixing?

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly is the situation here? It seems to me like you're saying that the "is accepted: yes" and "accepted: no" labels are inconsistent. But they're actually not. [The question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199769/how-to-cancel-request-with-retofit2-and-rxandroid) *does* have an accepted answer, it's just not 2Tu's, because that one has been deleted.

Comment: Well, the labels *also* claim 2Tu's answer to be the only one. Therefore, yes, the labels *are* inconsistent.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287852/578411

Comment: Not a duplicate. That the system can be cheated by looking at the actual post is another problem entirely from leaking the information into the queue itself.

Comment: @Floern Technically question vs answer, but very closely related. Indeed, this question and its duplicate are the kind of meta post I searched before posting but couldn't find. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [Zero answers but accepted is "yes"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312267/zero-answers-but-accepted-is-yes) and [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug) we apparently don't care to prevent this.

> TL;DR If you are paying enough attention and spending enough time on a review task to figure out that a review is an audit, then the audit has already done its job.

Occasionally someone will (wrongly) fail a review due to this but this is not considered to be a big deal.